# Getting null in json_decode

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a text file that has json on it. example below:

```
{'something' : 'ss'}
```

I am trying to read it on php and convert it to an array using `json_decode`.

```
        $temp = '';
        $fh = fopen( '/quiz' . $testid . '.txt' ,'r');

        while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
            $temp .= $line;
        }
        fclose($fh);

        $temp = str_replace("\n","",$temp); //to remove new line
        $temp = str_replace("\r","",$temp);
        $temp = json_decode($temp);
```

But im getting `null`

If I don't `json_decode` it.. I can get the string.

I hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks,
E

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any parsing prior to calling `json_decode`

```
$contents = file_get_contents('/quiz' . $testid . '.txt');
$temp = json_decode($contents);
```

If you're still getting null, your JSON is likely invalid, you can use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to diagnose it.

Comment: Looks like your file is not JSON. Can you post more of it?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works so i think that's a problem with your file parsing algorithm

```
<?php
$temp = '';

$temp='{
"a":1,
"b":[1,2,3]
}';

$temp = str_replace("\n","",$temp); //to remove new line
$temp = str_replace("\r","",$temp);
$temp = json_decode($temp);
var_dump($temp);
?>
```

Comment: so try to put a echo of $temp after closing the file and show us the result

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](http://php.net/json_decode):

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values
>   true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL
>   respectively. **NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded** or if the
>   encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

The reason is that you don't have [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com).

```
Parse error on line 1:
{    'something': 'ss'}
-----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

You probably mean:

```
{
    "something": "ss"
}
```